How to define SwiftData #Index on an enum field?
I am implementing new #Index macro announced at WWDC24 for SwiftData. This is simplified code for my model
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


enum MyType: Int, Codable {
  case Type1
  case Type2
  case Type3
}


@Model
final class MyModel {
  #Index<MyModel>([\.type])
  
  var type: MyType
  var value: Int?
  var createdAt: Date
  
  init(
    type: MyType,
    value: Int?
  ) {
    self.type = type
    self.value = value
    self.createdAt = .now
  }
}

When I try to create ModelContainer for above, following error is thrown. I tried adding Equatable and CaseItterable to the enum, but with no luck. Hence the question, is there a way where I can create index on the enum?

Can't create an index element with composite property


The error message is quite clear so it doesn’t look like a bug but intended behavior, the interesting question is if this will not be supported or if it’s not implemented yet. Index is defined to take a PartialKeyPath as argument but there is (must be) some restrictions on what types that can be used so we also need some improved documentation.

For now, SwiftData doesn't allow you to index a composite property directly. You have to use the RawValue of your enum instead.
enum MyType: Int {
  case Type1
  case Type2
  case Type3
}

@Model
final class MyModel {
  #Index<MyModel>([\.typeRawValue])
  
  var typeRawValue: Int
  var value: Int?
  var createdAt: Date

  @Transient
  public var type: MyType {
    get { MyType(rawValue: typeRawValue)! }
    set { typeRawValue = newValue.rawValue }
  }
  
  init(
    type: MyType,
    value: Int?
  ) {
    self.typeRawValue = type.rawValue
    self.value = value
    self.createdAt = .now
  }
}


You should declare typeRawValue private.
